# How to submit passport at Canada VAC in Los Angeles

Tags: visas, canada, los-angeles

I have to submit my passport to a Canada VAC located in the US to process a tourist visa.

It appears I need to pre-pay for return shipping and I need to print the label from their portal online, but I don't receive any activation link when I try to register at https://www.vfsglobal.ca/PostalAppointment/.

Is it safe for me to just mail in my passport without this shipping label and hope they send it back?

Any advice for how I could contact a human at the VAC?

Comment: Have you [contacted VFS](https://visa.vfsglobal.com/usa/en/can/contact-us) (the operator of Canada's VAC in Los Angeles) to ask?

Comment: Ya. No response there.

Comment: How long has it been since you tried to register? Sometimes VFS can take several hours to send the link. Have you tried using another email?

Comment: I tried using another email. It’s been like 2 days - no activation email on either email

Comment: did you submit your passport ?
what courier service did you use ?

Comment: As of writing this on Jan-16, 2023, their phone lines had an automated message with no real information. They seem to be responsive to emails at `info.canny@vfshelpline.com`